# Disprove: "If $P(A) = P(B^C)$, then $(A^C) = B$."

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Disprove.** "If $P(A) = P(B^C)$, then $(A^C) = B$."

Please help. I really do not know how to solve this one.

Edit: This isn't probability, $P$ is the power set.

[Please disprove the first item in number 04.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjeaS.jpg)

Comment: What does $C$ mean here?

Comment: $B^C$ means complement of the $B$. That is how our professor indicates complement. Sorry about that.

Comment: But complement in what set?

Comment: It's a bit strange to use unqualified complement and power sets in the same breath. Unqualified complement will have to be relative to some base set, but then the power set will take you _out of_ that base set ...

Comment: The problem doesn't really say what set.

Comment: Is there any chance the problem actually said "Prove _or_ disprove"?

Comment: No. Just **disprove** the statement. I can take a picture but I don't know how to add here.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618315/disprove-if-pa-pbc-then-ac-b

Comment: Looking at the image in the question, if $P$ denotes the power set, then what do $P(A|C)$ and $P(B|C)$ mean? I think $P$ might be probability.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 is right, that image looks a lot like it's about probability rather than power sets. (And then it would actually make sense to _disprove_ rather than prove the claims).

Answer (score 4):

*Disprove*? The claim looks true to me, if we reformulate it to explicitly mention a base set for the complement operators:

> Assume that $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq X$. If $\mathcal P(A)=\mathcal P(X\setminus B)$, then $X\setminus A = B$.

**Proof.** You can reconstruct a set knowing its power set: for every $Y$ we have
$$ Y = \bigcup_{Z\in \mathcal P(Y)} Z $$
Therefore if $\mathcal P(Y_1)=\mathcal P(Y_2)$ then $Y_1=Y_2$.

Thus, given $\mathcal P(A)=\mathcal P(X\setminus B)$ we can conclude $A=X\setminus B$, which implies $X\setminus A=B$.